# Compute joint probability distribution of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, covariance, joint-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly normal random variables with mean 0 and covariance matrix
\begin{pmatrix} 1~~\rho \\ \rho~~1 \end{pmatrix}, where $\rho=-\frac{q}{1-q}$.

X and Y are used to define an expression, given below, which we want to numerically evaluate. This is mentioned as Corollary 18 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.03792.pdf) (page 21). It is also mentioned that numerically this expression is between 0.943 and 0.944. If would be great if someone can shed some light on how this is computed.

sup<sub>${q \in (0,1/2)}$</sub> $\left(1-\Pr\left[(X\leq \Phi^{-1}(q) ~\land ~(Y\leq \Phi^{-1}(q)\right]\right)$, where $\Phi$ is the cumulative density function of the standard normal distribution.

Any help is appreciated. How would one approach solving this problem?

Comment: What does "$\Lambda$" refer to?  Would that be a typographical error for "$\cap$" or perhaps "$\wedge$"?

Comment: Yeah, I meant logical AND, edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Two things are strange about this question and need fixing.  First, the paper doesn't have a page 22.  On its p. 21 there is an expression that sort of looks like yours but it's actually quite different.  Indeed, the expression you are trying to optimize is not defined when $0\lt q \lt 1/11,$ indicating there's some typographical error.

Comment: I updated the question based on your feedback. I needed to compute a slightly different expression than the one mentioned in the paper. But, as you rightly pointed out there were typographical errors. It would be useful for me to know how the expression in the paper is numerically computed. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks.